# awk command in bash: how to stop new line being added?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, scripting, command-line-interface

I have multiple bash code file, with 3-4 lines in each (like the following).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "xy"
echo "x.com"
echo "z"
```

I want to have the output csv file like following (output of each file in a line of a csv file)

```
|name|sit|alternate_name
|:----|:----:|----|
|x|x.com|z
|y|y.com|f
```

but I'm getting the output like-

```
||
|:----:|
|x|
|x.com|
|z|
|y|
|y.com|
|f|
```

My code is as follows-

```
for i in $(ls script_B*)
do
    ./$i | awk -F ':' '{OFS=",";print $1,$2,$3}' >> output.csv
done
```

I'm a noob in this area and couldn't do much study on awk.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you just use `printf` instead of `print`? `printf("%s %s %s", $1, $2, $3);` probably

Comment: `$1` et al. are fields in a *single* line of input, not the first three lines of input.

Comment: The script you posted can't possibly produce the output you say it does, and you've obviously written it to expect `:`-separated input and produce `,`-separated output when your shell script doesn't print any `:`s to it's output, and your expected output is `|`-separated and has header lines that don't exist in the input or in your awk script. Please [edit] your question to the input/output/code all make sense relative to each other so we can best help you.

Comment: I see you accepted the first answer you got that produces the output you expect thereby discouraging anyone else from posting an answer so if there is a better answer you'll probably never hear about it. Getting the expected output from some sample input is the starting point for finding an answer, not the end point. It's usually best to give it a few hours or a day after posting a question before accepting an answer so you can what answers are possible and choose the best one rather than just assuming the first answer you got is the best possible answer (which it MAY be in this case, idk).

Comment: Yeah. I feel so. Thanks @EdMorton for pointing to that. Actually couldn't have much time to go through the details for now. But surely, I will come back again to know the more proper way to do the task.

Comment: As an aside, the [`ls` is useless.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: @NishatTamanna my point is that since accepting an answer discourages other people from posting answers you're now  unlikely to see [many] additional answers if/when you come back to this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accumulate 3 lines of input before writing a line of output, something like

```
$ awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS=","} NR % 3 == 1 {line1=$0} NR % 3 == 2 {line2=$0} NR % 3 == 0 { print line1, line2, $0 }' <<EOF
x
x.com
z
EOF
x,x.com,z
```

`NR` is the number of the current input line (starting with 1). Compute the remainder modulo 3 tells you if you are on the first, second, or third line of an input group. If each `awk` is only reading a single 3-line file, you can simplify that to

```
% awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS=","} NR == 1 {line1=$0} NR == 2 {line2=$0} NR == 3 { print line1, line2, $0 }' <<EOF
x
x.com
z
EOF
x,x.com,z
```

In the first two cases, you have to remember the current line with a variable until `awk` reads the last line; I'm not aware of a version of `awk` that allows you to consume more lines of input *within* a single action.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that `xargs -L` can be helpful in this regard as well:

```
for i in script_B*
do
  "$i" | xargs -L3 
done
```

While this is not the best application of this trick (it can easily break when you try to put commas in), I find it extremely helpful for when I'm grep'ing for results and they arrive on two different lines.  For instance:

```
command | grep -e "IP|status" | xargs -L2
```

Anyway, back to your question, you can put commas into the output, but it's not reliable since it breaks if any of your scripts generate a line with spaces:

```
for i in script_B*
do
  "$i" | xargs -L3 
done  | tr " " ","
```

Comment: `paste - - -` would also be appropriate.